# How to make connection between two Android devices via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have tried to connect two devices by using the Android Bluetooth Chat example on  the Android developer site. It's only connecting from one of the devices and when I am trying to connect from the other device it's not connecting and pops up a message "Unable to connect: [device  name here]".

I am wondering if I'm using the same code on both of the devices, why is the connection made only from one side, and being refused from the other side?

I have 2 devices - 1 running version 2.2 and 1 running v2.3.3.
My request is always being sent from my Galaxy Y running 2.3.3  to a Galaxy fit-v running Android 2.2, but not vice versa. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:

        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            FaceCardList.requestConnection = true;
            FaceCardList.deviceSelected = false;

            address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);              
            
            device = FaceCardList.mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

            // Attempt to connect to the device
            FaceCardList.mChatService.connect(device);
            // Get the device MAC address
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
            setupChat();
        } else {
            // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

and the code for my BluetoothChat service is:

```
public class BluetoothChatService extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothChat";
    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID =  UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // ("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler
     *            A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = FaceCardList.mBluetoothAdapter;
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * 
     * @param state
     *            An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        }
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(FaceCardList.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1)
                .sendToTarget();
    }
    
    /**
     * Return the current connection state.
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "start");
        }

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * 
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) {
          Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);         
        }

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * 
     * @param socket
     *            The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket,
            BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "######connected");
        }

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one
        // device
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FaceCardList.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FaceCardList.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        }
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * 
     * @param out
     *            The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                return;
            }
        r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
  
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FaceCardList.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FaceCardList.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FaceCardList.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FaceCardList.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted (or
     * until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                
                tmp = mAdapter
                        .listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
//                if(!tmp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
           
   //               
      //          }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (D) {
               Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            }
            
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
    
                
                    try {
                        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        //e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate
                            // new socket.
                            //Log.e("STATE_CONNECTED: service","STATE_CONNECTED: service");
                                    
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                //Log.e(TAG,"Could not close unwanted socket",                                                e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
            }
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection with a
     * device. It runs straight through; the connection either succeeds or
     * fails.
     */
      private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket= null;

        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            System.out.println("my uuid :-"+MY_UUID);
            try {
                try {
                    //tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    
                    mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    
                    System.out.println("mm socket value :-"+mmSocket);
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("error in connecting :-"+e.getMessage());
                     //Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 

            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
            
         //   mmSocket = tmp;
            System.out.println("mm socket value as temp :-----------------");
        }

        
   

       
          @Override
           public void run() {
            //Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                System.out.println("before connection");
                
                mmSocket.connect();
                System.out.println("after connection ");
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("in connection failed :-"+e.getMessage());
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    //Log.e(TAG,"unable to close() socket during connection failure",                                    e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                
                try {
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();  
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("in connection failed start bluetooth chat service :-"+e2.getMessage());
                }
                
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device. It handles all
     * incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        private final InputStream mmInStream;

        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected                                                                                                                                                                                        
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream\
                    
                    
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    
                    // XXX !!!
                    String buffer2 = new String(buffer);
                    buffer2= buffer2.substring(0, buffer2.length()-3)+"\n";
                    
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(FaceCardList.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer2.getBytes()).sendToTarget();
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * 
         * @param buffer
         *            The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                
                // XXX !!!
                String buffer2 = new String(buffer);
                buffer2= buffer2.substring(0, buffer2.length()-2);
                mHandler.obtainMessage(FaceCardList.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                        buffer2.getBytes()).sendToTarget();
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck. Why is the connection always made from the higher version to a lower version but not from the lower version to a higher one?

Comment: I've just offered a bounty on this question, as I've experienced trouble with Bluetooth in the past. It seems like a lot of the trouble stems from the hardware, choice of UUID, etc. rather than the actual code, and there aren't many answers on StackOverflow that helped me out. If you wouldn't mind cleaning up your code (properly indenting it, etc., that'd be great (it'll attract more people if your code is readable).

Comment: At this point, I've pretty much given up on anyone giving a 100% helpful answer. I really don't want my 50 points to go to waste, so I will happily award the bounty for a **well thought out answer**, even if it doesn't specifically solve the problem at hand. *Any tips, helpful advice, experience with Bluetooth programming is welcome*.

Comment: You can start [with](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) . It shows to connect two android devices.

Comment: Have you set the required `uses privilege` inside your XML for the Bluetooth? (Pretty sure you did, but it may be a hint)

Comment: yes i did..@EvilGoat

Answer (score 5):

I have done this,and i think you get connection lost when the device discoverable change.  Please do check the device discoverable in both,you can enable it by code.

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Saurabh, make this change please and watch it work:

```
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9) { // VK: Build.Version_Codes.GINGERBREAD is not accessible yet so using raw int value
                // VK: 9 is the API Level integer value for Gingerbread
                try {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Method m = null;
                try {
                    m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, (UUID) MY_UUID);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if just copy the code straight away and try to run it if so, bear in mind `android.app.ActionBar`; require version 3.0. Also Bluetooth communication is not exactly peer to peer it's  Master Slave.

Answer (score 1):

I also think your problem is not within your code.

Two Years ago I have modified the BluetoothChat example application. You can find the modified project here - [Bluetooth Chat](https://github.com/biafra23/BluetoothChat) and the binary here: [Bluetooth Chat](https://github.com/biafra23/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.apk/qr_code)

If this works better between your two devices it might help.

I tested it just now on Android version 2.3.3 (Nexus One) and on Version 4.0.4 (Galaxy Nexus).