# Bluetooth paired devices connection problems

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm having issues with connecting. At first it works, than it does not, unless I unpair the devices.
I've gotten every possible exception that could happen, socket closed, pipe closed, connection refused, port already in use, etc.

I'm aware that there are issues with bluetooth on android pre 4.2 (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37725).

Devices that I'm having problems with connecting these devices:

- Htc one(android 4.2)
- samsung galaxy s2(android 4.1.2)
- nexus 4 (4.3)
- samsung galaxy s4 (4.2)

Another minor issue is, that the paired devices are not stored (mostly on the nexus 4, and the sgs2).

Here is my code:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //this is the other one that I've tried: fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

private static final String NAME = "BluetoothConnector";

public void listenForConnection() throws IOException, BluetoothException {
//first close the socket if it is open
closeSocket();

BluetoothServerSocket mServerSocket = null;
try {
    mServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID_SECURE); //ioexception here!         
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        try { //this is a stupid hack, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480480/rfcomm-connection-between-two-android-devices
            Method m = mBluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] { int.class });
            mServerSocket = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(mBluetoothAdapter, PORT);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(ex);
            throw e;
        }
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}

while (!isCancelled) {
    try {
        socket = mServerSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } finally {
                socket = null;
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }

    if (socket == null) {
        throw new BluetoothException("Socket connection connected, but null");
    } else {
        isConnected = true;
        break; // everything is ok
    }
}
}



public void connect(String address) throws IOException, BluetoothException {
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

try {
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Log.e(e1);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        try {
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
            socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, PORT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e);
            throw e1;
        }
    } else {
        throw e1;
    }
}

// Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
try {
    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
    // successful connection or an exception
    socket.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
    // Close the socket
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        Log.e(e2);
        Log.wtf("unable to close() socket during connection failure");
    }
    throw e;
}
```

}

```
private void closeSocket() {
    try {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
            socket = null;
            Log.d("Socket closed");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(e);
        Log.wtf("close() of connect socket failed");
    }
}
```

I tried changing the uuid(random one also), tried looking at older sdk samples.
So what could be wrong here?

edit: trying to clarify: the problem usually comes up, when 2 devices that have been paired, connected, did some successful communication, get disconnected (by the user). After that, they can not be reconnected, unless they get rebooted, or unpaired manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at this point Bluetooth is broken on android.

There is no sure way of connecting 2 devices, that works all the time.
[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954642/unable-to-make-connection-between-2-device-bluetooth-android?rq=1) are using an unofficial way to do it, but that does not work on all devices.

I did some in house testing, with the top 10 devices, that are on the market currently, so after around around 90 test runs, the hacked method worked 75% of the time, which is not good enough.

For example, the htc oneX will just handle incoming Bluetooth request, as a Bluetooth hands free device(it is connecting succesfully!), but makes messaging impossible.

After implementing full Bluetooth functionality, we decided to remove it from our app, and release it without it. We'll switch to wifi in some later release.

Answer (score 1):

> You are trying to paired this manner:

```
private void TwitPairedDevice() {
    buttonTwitPairDevice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> fetchPairedDevices=bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
            Iterator<BluetoothDevice> iterator=fetchPairedDevices.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                final BluetoothDevice pairBthDevice=iterator.next();
                final String addressPairedDevice=pairBthDevice.getAddress();
                AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asynchPairDevice=new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                        try {
                            socket=pairBthDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                            socket.connect();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    }
                };asynchPairDevice.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> Connect Pired Device:

```
    private void FetchPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices=bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
        for(BluetoothDevice pairedBthDevice:pairedDevices)
        {
            listPairedDevice.add(pairedBthDevice.getName());
        }
        listviewPairedDevice.setAdapter(adapterPairedDevice);
        listviewPairedDevice.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Object listPairedName=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                String selectedPairedName=listPairedName.toString();
                Set<BluetoothDevice> bthDeviceChecking=bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
                for(final BluetoothDevice bthDevice:bthDeviceChecking)
                {
                    if(bthDevice.getName().contains(selectedPairedName))
                    {
                        listPairDevice.clear();
                        listPairDevice.add(bthDevice);
                        final String addressPairedDevice=bthDevice.getAddress();
                        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asynTask=new AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                                try {
                                    socket=bthDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                                    socket.connect();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return null;
                            }
};
                        asynTask.execute(arg2);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Going trough all available paired devices won't make sense in my case. I want the user to connect, to a specific device.

Comment: k you will be display your paired device in listview and then click the your wanted paired device to pair that device...i posted some code  for connect the paired device see it...